# bcrypt next() is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var mongoose =  require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username:{type: String,lowercase: true, required: true,unique:true},
    password:{type:String, required:true},
    email:{type:String,required:true,lowercase:true,unique:true},
});

// mongoose middleware
UserSchema.pre('save',(req,res,next)=>{
    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password,null,null,(err,hash)=>{
        if(err) return next(err);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
 });
 module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

below the error i can't find out the error

POST /users 200 58.468 ms - 14
    /var/www/html/meanstacktutorial/app/models/user.js:17
            next();
            ^

```
ReferenceError: next is not defined
    at bcrypt.hash (/var/www/html/meanstacktutorial/app/models/user.js:17:9)
    at /var/www/html/meanstacktutorial/node_modules/bcrypt-nodejs/bCrypt.js:631:3
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

when i make password to encrypt then it gets some error like "next() is not defined " why i don't know exactly ..i have been trying to slove the problem but i couldn't please help me out thank you

Comment: Can you please include the code from models/user.js where you're using bcrypt

Comment: added it top please find out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed to your pre-save hook should only take **next** as an argument.

You have also passed in **req** and **res**.

Try this instead:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, null, null, (err, hash) => {
    if(err) return next(err);
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much .. I made mistake actually  that

Comment: General Note: using bcrypt.hash without a salt is not recommended as you're left vulnerable to brute-force methods